# ASP.NET MVC 5 Default WebApp Forgot Password module missing?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

In MVC 4 with SimpleMembership all these functions come with the default webbapp that you create in Visual Studio.

I was wondering where I can find the same for MVC 5 using the new ASP.NET Identity membership system? Is there some official blog or something that is beeing hidden from me in google search results?

**UPDATE1**: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/12/20/announcing-preview-of-microsoft-aspnet-identity-2-0-0-alpha1.aspx

**UPDATE2**: ASP.NET Identity 2.0 RTM has been released. Forgot Password is included in the samples/templates. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/20/test-announcing-rtm-of-asp-net-identity-2-0-0.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are working on adding these features to the ASP.NET Identity system and the MVC 5 templates.

Comment: One good list as expected by most users,  http://brockallen.com/2013/10/20/the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-of-asp-net-identity/#ugly  I know of the upcoming OwinMiddleware, in 1.1, future version expected to provide blocks for the features listed in link.

Comment: Cool, will hold my horses then and continue with some other stuff in my app in the meantime. :)

Comment: Hello Pranav. Do you know what the approximate time frame is for the release of those features? The whole ASP.NET MVC 5 Internet Template is kind of pointless without this feature. It would also be great if in the UserManager Library a new "ChangePassword" method is added that doesn't require the current password to be known, so Administrative Users can reset passwords for locked out users. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this as well. To fix it, I created some controller actions in `AccountController.cs` (and corresponding views) to handle it.

Here are the actual lines that reset the user's password:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ResetForgottenPassword(string key, ManageUserViewModel model)
{
    var user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.ForgotPasswordCode != null && u.ForgotPasswordCode == key);

    if (user == null || !user.ForgotPasswordDate.HasValue || user.ForgotPasswordDate.Value.AddDays(1) < DateTime.UtcNow)
            return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();

    ModelState state = ModelState["OldPassword"];
    if (state != null)
    {
        state.Errors.Clear();
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (UserManager.HasPassword(user.Id))
            UserManager.RemovePassword(user.Id);

        IdentityResult result = UserManager.AddPassword(user.Id, model.NewPassword);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            //Clear forgot password temp key
            user.ForgotPasswordCode = null;
            user.ForgotPasswordDate = null;
            db.SaveChanges();

            //Sign them in
            var identity = UserManager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = false }, identity);

            return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess });
        }
        else
        {
            AddErrors(result);
        }
    }

    ViewBag.ForgotPasswordCode = key;

    return View(model);
}
```

Some custom items are the new fields on the user object:

- `ForgotPasswordCode` and `ForgotPasswordDate` to keep track of the user throughout the "reset password email" process.
- I pass the key around in in the `ViewBag` once the user arrives from the email link.
- The `db` variable is a property of my database context class inherited from a base controller.
- I use UTC DateTimes in my database. Change `DateTime.UtcNow` to `DateTime.Now` if you do not.

Probably not the best solution, but it's a fairly quick and simple patch.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a reset password by yourself (not sure that is the better choice, but is better than nothing)

Generate the hash with:

```
var newPwdHash = new PasswordHasher().HashPassword(newPasswordPlain)
```

And replace to the user's passwordhash property

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot wait for the ASP.NET Identity Team to add this feature you can get an implementation of password reset from the [open source project SimpleSecurity](http://simplesecurity.codeplex.com/). Just take a look at the [ResetPassword action on the AccountController](http://simplesecurity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#AspNetIdentity/SimpleSecurity.AspNetIdentity.RefApp/Controllers/AccountController.cs).  You can [read about how the password reset was implemented here](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/04/password-reset-with-simplemembership.html). Although the article references SimpleMembership, SimpleSecurity uses the same API to support either SimpleMembership or ASP.NET Identity in your MVC application.